# Perl POD: line feed

Tags: perl

I use Pod to write manuals for my program. And I ran into a problem. Please tell me how to solve it.

I have the following code:

```
#include <myhead.h>

I<void> myfunc (I<int arg1>, I<int arg2>);
```

I would like the text to be written from the next line after the word 'void'. Moreover, it is with the next line, and not through one.

Comment: This looks like a C program. Are you using Perl to generate documentation for a C program?

Comment: Yes, I use pod2man and create manuals in several languages.

Answer (score 3):

Pod is "plain ol' documentation" and doesn't have fancy features. It sounds like you want the text after `void` to be on the next line. In that case, you have to put that text on the next line and make it verbatim text so it retains the formatting:

```
=pod

    #include <myhead.h>

    I<void> 
    myfunc (I<int arg1>, I<int arg2>);

=cut
```

If you need something else, improve your questions by showing exactly what you expect.

But, I expect that you probably want to write your own Pod formatter. Then you can do exactly what you want. Fo what it's worth, I write all of my books in Pod and use several custom formatters to get them into their end states.

Comment: I suppose the "= pod" insertion is unnecessary - the file initially has a .pod extension and contains only man. If I write indented then format codes are not executed.

Answer (score 1):

Pod has paragraph breaks and preformatted text, but no line breaks.

If you are targeting a particular output format, you can do, for example:

```perl
=begin html 

One line
Another line

=end html
```

Or you could do some kind of post-processing on the file.